# OpenId Connect reauthentication with only a token

Tags: openid-connect

Is it possible to restablish a session to a OpenId Connect authorization server  (get cookies set in browser) without passing credentials (for example id token or access token or any minimal data that doesn't include user credentials) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an extension of the core OpenID Connect specification called OpenID Connect Session Management (http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-session-1_0.html) that allows for this type of functionality.

When refreshing the session the RP would send an Authentication Request with the `prompt=none` parameter and an `id_token_hint` that contains the current `id_token`. The OpenID Connect RP may then issue a new `id_token` and return it to the RP in an Authentication Response. See the last 2 paragraphs of section http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-session-1_0.html#RPiframe

Comment: Thanks Hans. Would this method also update the corresponding browser cookies?

Comment: Yes that's up to the RP